# How can I maximize our team score in Junkenstein's Revenge?

Tags: overwatch

My goal is to hit 5 gold stars, but no matter how well our team communicates, even in a pre-made 4 man brawl, where all of us are supporting each other, and not dying at all, we can just barely clear 4 stars in the results screen.

How can I maximize the team score in Junkenstein's Revenge? Do I need to be getting more headshots?  Is team accuracy factored in, is how fast we clear the waves factored in?

Comment: This is hard mode, I assume (since you can only get 5 stars in hard mode)? Did the doors take any damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a little late since the Halloween event is ending, but my friends and I spent the past couple days figuring out the scoring on the event.

There are 3 main sources of points on the brawl:

1. Door Health

   - Taking damage on the door results in a static loss of points, as well as losing the potential points for killing the zomnic/shock tire that damages it.
2. Survival Bonus

   - There are incremental survival bonuses that are awarded throughout the game, up until the last boss fight.
   - These bonuses increase over time as long as nobody dies. When someone dies, the bonus is reduced significantly.
3. Elite Bonus

   - The speed at which you kill each boss adds a bonus on to the total score.
   - There is a max of 100 bonus for each Reaper, 250 for Roadhog and Junkenstein each, and ~200 for Mercy (maybe more?)

Additionally, the Elite and Survival bonuses seem to get multiplied by some factor when the final score is applied on a win.

I don't know exact calculations of the various final bonuses, but I can say that to get a high score you should:

- Die as little as possible
- Kill elites as quickly as possible
- Don't let the door take damage

A 5-star score is possible with deaths, door damage, and/or slow boss kills, as long as you make up for it in good performance in other areas.

Some reference playthrough videos:

- [23k score with deaths, door damage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6C4d8A87c9M)
- [28k score with fast boss kills](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfW68eHcSeE&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a theory, i've noticed that whenever you kill a large group of enemies really fast (ultiing) you gain a score bonus. This tells me that you should save your ults and use them simultaneously and try and get as many kills as possible with them. this will increase your score gain. i have not been able to pull this off myself tho because i dont know when and where. but this is what i've noticed

Comment: In addition to this, I think the speed at which you kill bosses counts. I had been using ult-combo spam with friends and would top out at 25.9k or so. Then yesterday, I played a game where we killed the roadhogs in record time (tons of hanzo headshots) and got 27.5k (top 20 NA)

Answer (score 0):

Have mcree hold the left corrador that is ul the stairs he can solo hold it and his ult can clear things up easy if you get overwhelmed
Have ana sit back and primarily heal, dont g for kills as her. Focus her grenade on roadhog when he spawns and focus fire the wheel whenever possible
Have hanzo hold the right lane and help wih the middle his scatter arrow is great for right lane
Soldger 76 and ana both work on middle lane and heal eachother
Ana is only really good as a healer and to sleepdart
Dr.junkenstein as mcree preps his ult to one shot him and mercy

Comment: This doesn't explain anything about team score.

Comment: I assume this is what you normally do. Sounds like a reasonable plan. Have you achieved 5 stars doing this?